# Is it support Application cache in multiple server in asp.net(C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

Is it support Application cache in multiple server in asp.net(C#). I know application variable is not supporting in multiple server (web farms), But what about application cache? .Will be there any issue whiling access the values or it not worth to store values in application cache when we are going with multiple server? (Database storing not suitable, it will take more load). Here i am using codes

```
     HybridDictionary dicApplicationVariable = new HybridDictionary();
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["dicApplicationVariable"] != null)
                    {
                        dicApplicationVariable = (HybridDictionary)HttpContext.Current.Cache["dicApplicationVariable"];
                        if (dicApplicationVariable.Contains(dtUserLogin.Rows[0]["Id"]))
                        {
                            dicApplicationVariable.Remove(dtUserLogin.Rows[0]["Id"]);
                            dicApplicationVariable.Add(dtUserLogin.Rows[0]["Id"], LogginSessionID);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dicApplicationVariable.Add(dtUserLogin.Rows[0]["Id"], LogginSessionID);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dicApplicationVariable.Add(dtUserLogin.Rows[0]["Id"], LogginSessionID);
                        HttpContext.Current.Cache["dicApplicationVariable"] = dicApplicationVariable;
                    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running Windows Server 2008 or later, then I would look into [Windows Server AppFabric Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334305.aspx).

> Windows Server AppFabric extends Windows Server to provide enhanced hosting, management, and caching capabilities for Web applications and middle-tier services. The AppFabric hosting features add service management extensions to Internet Information Services (IIS), Windows Process Activation Service (WAS), and the .NET Framework 4. This includes Hosting Services and Hosting Administration tools that make it easier to deploy, configure, and manage Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) and Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) based services. The AppFabric caching features add a distributed, in-memory object cache to Windows Server that makes it easier to scale out high-performance .NET applications, especially ASP.NET applications.

I realize that not everyone will want to use Microsoft products, so here are some alternatives to AppFabric:

- [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) - this is a third party, not free, solution
- Redis via [Open Source C# Client for Redis - ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis). Here is an interesting read on [.NET Application Caching: Redis vs. AppFabric Caching 1.1](http://www.dexterlegaspi.com/2012/10/05/net-application-caching-redis-vs-appfabric-caching-1-1/).

Comment: I'm conflicted; I'd upvote this answer because it answers the question alright but I've had horrible experiences with AppFabric in the past and I got the feeling it's not really a product that will move forward much. Perhaps I'm wrong but either way, please note there are alternatives. Any distributed cache system can be integrated with ASP.Net's cache fairly easily, and many already have ASP.Net providers for that. @OP: Also note that any sort of distributed cache will be generally slower than direct memory access.

Comment: @AlexPaven - understood and I realize that AppFabric will not be for everyone. :-)

Comment: If possible please tell me any alter solution ? I think this shared cache is only possible with 3 rd party apps (i dont need)

Comment: There is no built-in solution (other than DB store of cached items, which is indeed not such a great idea) so any answer will involve third-party libraries I'm afraid. Unless you'll want to build your own (highly unrecommended).

Comment: http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20030420.asp Please refer this link and tell me Is it poosible?

Comment: @Haris - I have never tried this, but it looks and sounds reasonable, give it a try and let us know. :-)